# Index limit as subtraction of indices

Tags: c, arrays, indexing

I have my problem based on something like below:

```
for(j = 0; j < LenA; j++)

   for(k = 0; k <= (j - k); k++)

    // some operation
```

If j = 1; k should run for 2 itrs. 0 and 1 however it exits after 1st iteration alone (k = 0). Why is this the case ?

Comment: Because `1` is not `<=` `(1 - 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration of the loop when j is equal to 1 you have

```
for(k = 0; 0 <= 1; k++)
```

after that iteration k becomes equal to 1 so the condition in the loop looking like

```
for(k = 0; 1 <= 0; k++)
```

evaluates to false.

Comment: Thanks Vlad.
Would you have an idea if I had to run k for 2 itrs. for 1 itr of j (at j = 1), what would need to be done ?

Comment: @samz12 just write in the loop k < j + 1

Comment: @samz12 Or k <= j.